# JAVA trouble with control flow and strings in school project

Tags: java, string, loops

This is what my code needs to do:

"This code takes a string as input and returns 0 if the string is empty, contains only whitespace, or does not start with a number or +/-. Otherwise, the code will return the string as a trimmed number(no leading or trailing whitespace) with no trailing letters following the numbers."

This is what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class stringManipulator 
{
    public static void main (String[]args) 
    {
        //initialize new system.in scanner object named input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //initialize variables
        int index = 0;
        
        //prompt user for a string as input
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        
        //store user input in string variable str
        String str = input.nextLine();
        
        //edit and output user inputed string
        if(str.length()==0)
        {
            System.out.println("return 0: String is empty");
        }
        else if(str.trim().length()==0)
        {
            System.out.println("return 0: String is only whitespace");
        }
        else while(index<str.length() && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(index)))
        {
            System.out.print(str.charAt(index));
            index++;
        }

        //close input scanner object
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Im having trouble with a few things:

1. I cant seem to get my while loop to keep the '+' or '-' in my output.
2. I cant seem to get the while loop to trim leading and trailing whitespace from my output.
3. Im having trouble getting the program to detect if the first character is not a digit or '+' or '-' before executing the loop.

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `else while` doesn't exists, put the whole while loop in the else block

Comment: yeah like azro said, `else while` is not valid java. You could just change it to `else if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to implement functionality in a separate method returning a specific result to facilitate testing.

```java
private static String process(String str) {
    if (null == str || str.isEmpty()) {
        return "0: empty";
    }
    str = str.trim();
    if (str.isEmpty()) {
        return "0: whitespace";
    }
    char first = str.charAt(0);
    if (!(Character.isDigit(first) || first == '+' || first == '-')) {
        return "0: not a number";
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            sb.append(c);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    // additional validation of inputs like +asd, -dsf
    if (sb.length() == 0 && (first == '+' || first == '-')) {
        return "0: not a signed number";
    }

    return first + sb.toString();
}
```

Test:

```java
String[] tests = {
    "", "acv", "-", "+", "12", "-01", "12dgr", "12+12", "34 23", "45-34", 
    "+346", "-14", "-fe", "+hrr", "-12ggg", "+43gd"
};

Arrays.asList(tests).forEach(s -> System.out.printf("'%s' -> %s%n", s, process(s)));
```

Output:

```
'' -> 0: empty
'acv' -> 0: not a number
'-' -> 0: not a signed number
'+' -> 0: not a signed number
'12' -> 12
'-01' -> -01
'12dgr' -> 12
'12+12' -> 12
'34 23' -> 34
'45-34' -> 45
'+346' -> +346
'-14' -> -14
'-fe' -> 0: not a signed number
'+hrr' -> 0: not a signed number
'-12ggg' -> -12
'+43gd' -> +43
```

Also, regular expressions may be used to validate input and remove redundant parts.
Assuming that a valid integer is to be returned, the method may be implemented as follows:

```java
private static int processReg(String str) {
    str = str.trim();
    if (str.isEmpty() || !str.matches("[-+\\d]\\d+.*")) { // does not start with digit,+,-
        return 0;
    }
    String num = str.replaceAll("[^-+0-9]", " ") // make "not-numeric" symbols blank
                    .trim()
                    .replaceAll("([-+\\d]\\d+)(.*)", "$1");  // keep the first number
    return Integer.parseInt(num);
}
```

Test:

```java
Arrays.asList(tests).forEach(s -> System.out.printf("'%s' -> %d%n", s, processReg(s)));
```

Output less verbose:

```
'' -> 0
'acv' -> 0
'-' -> 0
'+0' -> 
'12' -> 12
'-01' -> -1
'12dgr' -> 12
'12+12' -> 12
'34 23' -> 34
'45-34' -> 45
'+346' -> 346
'-14' -> -14
'-fe' -> 0
'+hrr' -> 0
'-12ggg' -> -12
'+43gd' -> 43
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class stringManipulator {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(readNumber(scan));
    }

    public static String readNumber(Scanner scan) {
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        String str = scan.nextLine();

        if (str.isEmpty())
            return "return 0: String is empty";
        if (str.trim().isEmpty())
            return "return 0: String is only whitespace";
        if (str.charAt(0) != '+' && str.charAt(0) != '-' && !Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0)))
            return "return 0: String does not start with a number or +/-";

        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
            if (i == 0 || Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
                buf.append(str.charAt(i));

        return buf.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being the solution I came to, thanks for all the feedback and help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class stringManipulator 
{
    public static void main (String[]args) 
    {
        //initialize new system.in scanner object named input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //initialize variables
        int index = 1;
        
        //prompt user for a string as input
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        
        //store trimmed user input in string variable str
        String str = input.nextLine();
        str = str.trim();
        
        //test if string is empty or contains only whitespace
        if(str.length()==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Return 0: String is empty or is only whitespace");
        }
        //tests if string starts with a digit, '+', or '-'
        else if (str.charAt(0) == '+' || str.charAt(0) == '-' || Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0)))
        {   
            //prints '+', '-', or first digit of string
            System.out.print(str.charAt(0));
            
            //loop prints characters of str up to string length as long as they are digits
            while(index<str.length() && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(index)))
            {
                System.out.print(str.charAt(index));
                index++;
            }
        }
        //output if the string starts with anything other than '+', '-', or a digit
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Return 0: String is not a number or does not begin with '+' or '-'");
        }

        //close input scanner object
        input.close();
    }
}
```